# Options to create a macOS recovery disk only with recovery tools included?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, usb, recovery, bootable-disk

I have several Macbooks available that need to be restored, and cannot be connected to the network due to their location, and other conditions. At the workplace I was provided with a USB flash drive that is not large enough to fit the entire recovery environment. I just cannot buy a new flash drive because only approved equipment is allowed to be used.

My question is can I create a recovery disk for macOS while not installing the entire system image, but only the recovery tools that come with it (including, perhaps, recovery via the Internet)?

I did not find options for recording an image without the system itself, although I know that recoveryOS is a separate part not related to macOS, so I ask for help here.

Macbooks models is
A1465 A1466 and A1465
Planning to get recovery programs from High Sierra pack

Comment: Wouldn't the obvious first step be to ask for a bigger USB stick? Ask them if it's worth the time taken in terms of your salary compared to the 20 bucks for a larger drive.

Comment: You're not going to be able to do an internet recovery if you can't connect them to a network. One or the other... Agreed, ask for a bigger stick.

Comment: Of course it is, but they provide only one type of USB sticks for workers due to their dumb "safe policy", thanks for that question

Comment: Do they have an approved HDD or SSD you could use instead that's big enough?

Comment: I know that my workspace clearly is not the best place, but i have this conditions and i can't do much about it (i asked already) that's why i'm here. No easy solutions here sadly

Comment: The next issue you'll hit is that modern Macbooks won't boot from an external drive unless it's been pre-approved on that Mac. The third may be the signature on any 'tweaked' boot OS. Back on Mojave, you could boot to a 650MB Recovery easily. Monterey, I'm really not so sure. I'd see if you first can boot from a non-regulation external HD, before even thinking about shrinking one down to your 'regulation' USB stick. Do tell your employers they're just wasting money. TBH, if they won't even trust their own IT guys to carry a bootable suite of useful tools, they're being very short-sighted.

Comment: Yes, Macbooks in stock can be booted from external drives, it tested already, most of them is not new, so i don't think there would be much problems.

Comment: Please update your question with the Mac model, and what macOS version you're planning to install. The recovery page at https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201372 states a disk with at least 14GB free is required to create the install media. I'm having a look to see if there are any slimming-down options...

Comment: Those numbers don't work to identify Macs, I'm afraid - they cover multiple models across 5 years of production, 2012 to 2017 - though at least it excludes T2 models. See https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201372 All you need is a 16GB stick.

Comment: How large is the flash drives that you have? Can you get more than one?

Comment: `createinstallmedia` doesn't provide any slimming down options, but it does offer a 'fattening up' option that is supposed to download firmware and other things when building the install disk. On my M1 it downloaded a load of extra stuff, but all x64 looking... I suppose because it is building a Universal installer. That said, the above linked article says that a network is required during the install process anyway, maybe it can only provide some Apple Silicon things at install time. This violates your 'no network' stipulation. I think you need to have a serious talk with your management.

Comment: However, my test is with M1 and Monterey. I don't have your combination of hardware so YMMV.